# how to change the storage from phone memory to internal storage?

Tags: google-play-store, settings

Everytime I try to install anything from google playstore it says insufficient internal storage but actually it has internal storage. How can I solve this problem

Comment: Not clear what's the difference between "phone memory" and "internal storage" and which one has "actually storage".

Answer (score 1):

Apps are stored on the */data* partition, while the empty space you have is probably located on some other location, like internal SD card. Even if you have empty space elsewhere, apps couldn't be installed nowhere but on the  */data* partition.

There is a way to make */data* partition bigger by resizing your partitions (I've done it myself), but it's not recommended if you don't know what you're doing, since you can end up making your phone unusable.